# Can someone suggest resources to slang and particularly queer/ LGBTQ slang?

Tags: resource-request, sociolinguistics, slang

I am working on a paper on queer communication and I need resources for sociolinguistic studies on slang and queer/ LGBTQ slang. Thanks!